# LoadError on gem that is definitely installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've recently started working with Rails, and I'm starting to frequently get errors like 
`LoadError: cannot load such file -- capybara`

But capybara is definitely in my gemfile, and when I do `bundle list`, it's definitely there. This has happened with `thor` and with `tilt` and some others.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'    (Commented out because of Loaderror --thin)
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc


group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'capybara-rails'    (Added because of LoadError capybara/rails)
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

What's going on here?

gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.2.11)
      actionpack (= 4.2.11)
      actionview (= 4.2.11)
      activejob (= 4.2.11)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (4.2.11)
      actionview (= 4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      rack (~> 1.6)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      globalid (>= 0.3.0)
    activemodel (4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.2.11)
      activemodel (= 4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      arel (~> 6.0)
    activesupport (4.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.3, >= 0.3.4)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    arel (6.0.4)
    builder (3.2.3)
    byebug (10.0.2)
    capybara (3.12.0)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (~> 1.2)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    capybara-console (0.0.4)
      capybara
      rails (>= 3.0)
    capybara-rails (0.0.2)
      capybara
      capybara-console
      database_cleaner
      exception_notification
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.4)
    crass (1.0.4)
    database_cleaner (1.7.0)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    exception_notification (4.3.0)
      actionmailer (>= 4.0, < 6)
      activesupport (>= 4.0, < 6)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_bot (4.11.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_bot_rails (4.11.1)
      factory_bot (~> 4.11.1)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (0.9.5)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jbuilder (2.8.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.2)
    jquery-rails (4.3.3)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.6)
    loofah (2.2.3)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mini_mime (1.0.1)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.11.3)
    multi_json (1.13.1)
    nokogiri (1.8.5)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.3)
    rack (1.6.11)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.2.11)
      actionmailer (= 4.2.11)
      actionpack (= 4.2.11)
      actionview (= 4.2.11)
      activejob (= 4.2.11)
      activemodel (= 4.2.11)
      activerecord (= 4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.2.11)
      sprockets-rails
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.9)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
      loofah (~> 2.2, >= 2.2.2)
    railties (4.2.11)
      actionpack (= 4.2.11)
      activesupport (= 4.2.11)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.3.2)
    rdoc (4.3.0)
    regexp_parser (1.3.0)
    rspec-core (3.8.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.8.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.8.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-rails (3.8.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.8.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.8.0)
    rspec-support (3.8.0)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spring (2.0.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13)
    thor (0.20.3)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    turbolinks (5.2.0)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (1.2.5)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (4.1.20)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  byebug
  capybara
  capybara-rails
  coffee-rails (~> 4.1.0)
  database_cleaner
  factory_bot_rails
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  rails (~> 4.2)
  rspec-rails
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  sqlite3
  turbolinks
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.1
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock

Comment: @rderoldan1 Done, thanks.

Comment: Are you using an environment manager like rbenv or rvm? If so, make sure that the gem is installed for the version that your app is running in.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm in the Flatiron bootcamp so these are projects downloaded from their lessons.

Comment: Be sure to use bundle exec before your Rails and rake commands

Comment: bundle exec isn't helping for, say, `rspec`

Answer (score 0):

You must require it in `spec/rails_helper.rb`:

```
# spec/rails_helper.rb

require 'spec_helper'
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)
abort('The Rails environment is running in production mode!') if Rails.env.production?
require 'rspec/rails'

# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!
require 'capybara/rails'
```

This is explained prominently in the [capybara README](https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#setup):

> If the application that you are testing is a Rails app, add this line to your test helper file:
>
> `require 'capybara/rails'`